# jQuery function is affecting all buttons on my site

Tags: jquery

I recently asked my frontend designer to setup buttons in my account management page to send the request in the background to a processing page. He supplied me with this code:

```
 //Account
   $('button#changeemail').click(function(){
       var newEmail = $('input[name*=newEmail]').serialize();
       var confirmEmail = $('input[name*=confirmEmail]').serialize();
       var password = $('input[name*=password]').serialize();
       var data = newEmail + '&' + confirmEmail + '&' password + '&email=true';
       $.post('accountProcess.php', data, function(result){ 
           $('#emailError p').html(result);
       });
   });
   $('button#changepassword').click(function(){
       var currentPassword = $('input[name*=currentPassword]').serialize();
       var newPassword = $('input[name*=newPassword]').serialize();
       var confirmPassword = $('input[name*=confirmPassword]').serialize();
       var data = currentPassword + '&' + newPassword + '&' confirmPassword + '&password=true';
       $.post('accountProcess.php', data, function(result){ 
           $('#passwordError p').html(result);
       });
   });
```

However, this immediately ruins all buttons on my site that use a similar setup. When you try to click them or press the enter key to submit, they all do nothing. I don't know anything about front end development, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: What errors do you get in the Javascript console when you click a button that doesn't work? Hit F12 to open up the console.

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +` Wow. That is possibly the coolest thing ever. I never knew about that. I think that might have solved my problem. **EDIT:** Nope, can't find the strange +. But then again, I don't know javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a `+` in the function

```
 var data = newEmail + '&' + confirmEmail + '&' password + '&email=true';
```

needs to be

```
 var data = newEmail + '&' + confirmEmail + '&' + password + '&email=true';
```

Same thing with the second one.

Comment: You are king, today, Andrew. +1 upvote and the green checkmark for you. Thank you. **EDIT**: Okay, green checkmark for you in 3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

This is specifically targetting two elements, "#changepassword" and "#changeemail". The hash sign is indicating an "ID", meaning that there is only *one* of those elements per page. So nothing in that code should be affecting other elements on the page... there has to be additional code that is causing the error.

Although, if clicking the #changepassword or #changeemail link generates javascript errors, it could prevent other buttons from working if they are also dependent on javascript. So you need to find out if there are any errors being thrown, and post those into your question

Comment: Those elements aren't even on some of the pages that the buttons are broken on. When I comment out the new code, it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Without really having examined the code, my first suggestion is for you to download FireBug for FireFox, and then have the console- and net tabs open and active when you click the buttons. This will most likely give you some more information of what is going on.